# One JDBC data store for various ActiveMQ "Classic" nodes?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have two nodes of ActiveMQ "Classic" using the default kahaDB data storage. We want to bring more brokers into production and want them to share the same database (preferably Oracle) to persist messages. Is that possible? Are there multi-tenancy features built-in?

Comment: This isn't a programming question but rather a server administration/configuration question. Such questions belong on a site like Server Fault rather than here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't (fully) agree. On the receiving side, we have to deal with these incoming messages and have to rely on delivery. We had the occurance, that one of the nodes crashed and everything stored in there just disappeared. That is one of the reasons we want to monitor persistent DLQ or the queues in general.

Comment: Regardless of the context, _this_ question is not about programming. It is about how to configure the broker. Such questions don't belong on Stack Overflow. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ActiveMQ to be multi-tenant in a database, simple create separate schemas in Oracle for each ActiveMQ cluster. Primary-Failover (aka master-slave) nodes may share the same DB schema for HA failover.

Comment: Thx, made my day ...